# Sci-fi/Fantasy movie which identifies the Cow as the ugliest creature in the universe

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe

I am looking for a fantasy/science fiction movie which has galaxy cops coming to Earth.  The scene that I remember is one of the characters identifying a cow as the ugliest creature in the universe.

A group of young adults, none were big name stars at the time of the movie, arrived on Earth, in America.  They were looking for a criminal or a group of criminals.  They landed in a small town. The character that id'd the cow as "the ugliest creature in the universe" was an ugly, short, fat character.  He had a pointed head and waddled wherever he went.  That is pretty much all I remember.

Comment: Hi and hello, take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to see if you can add in any more details